# Hover effect on new click loaded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I added a hover effect that is working very well but the issue is that my hover effect is not visible when I load more items (on mouse click).
Working image:
http://prntscr.com/6w0s0h 
Not working part:
http://prntscr.com/6w0t04

This is the code i made for my hover effect:

```
 $('.holder').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var width = $(this).parent().width();
        var height = $(this).parent().height();
        var img = $(this).find('img');
        var hover_in = $(this).find('.holder_in');
        var hover_in_w = $(this).find('.holder_in').width();
        var hover_in_h = $(this).find('.holder_in').height();
        hover_in.css({
            display: 'block',
            width: width - 40,
            bottom: -hover_in_h*3
        });
        $(this).on( 'mouseenter', function() {
            $(img).animate({
                opacity: 0.8
            }, 200);
            $(hover_in).animate({
                bottom: 20
            }, 200);
        }).on( 'mouseleave', function() {
            $(img).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 200);
            $(hover_in).animate({
                bottom: -hover_in_h*3
            }, 200);
        });
 });
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This type of question really needs sample HTML too (e.g. in a JSFiddle).

Comment: I am using company product so i am not able to output the full code, i tried to present you the issue with the image and js hover i added in.

Comment: Hover is getting width and height from the holder:
http://prntscr.com/6w1do5
As you can see here on the second print the new loaded items are not getting the width and height from the holder:
http://prntscr.com/6w1duc

Comment: Without the initial styling, the animation of the hover_in makes little sense. Start with this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/1fdfqpsq/ and make it do your initial stuff. That will give everyone a starting point to work with :)

Comment: Please check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/1fdfqpsq/1/
That is the hover effect i have, if i load more items on click no width and height on the new hover holders. The hover block get the width and height on load, that is why the other after loaded items can't see the size.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can do to improve this.

In order to support dynamically added elements you normally resort to delegated event handlers. `on` support connecting to a non-changing ancestor element. This works by listening for the event and then applying the jQuery selector. That means the element only needs to match at event time and not when the event was registered. The default ancestor is `document`, if nothing is closer/convenient.

Try to reuse selector results where possible and not re-query them DOM. Just save them to a var. You have one called element, but that was never used again.

Also, you need to try ensure the css setup code is run before the first `mouseenter`. I did this by triggering a fake `mouseleave` event on all the holders.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.holder', function () {
    var img = $('img', this);
    $(img).animate({
        opacity: 0.8
    }, 200);
    $('.holder_in', this).animate({
        bottom: 20
    }, 200);
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.holder',  function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var height = element.parent().height();
    var hover_in = element.find('.holder_in');
    var hover_in_h = hover_in.height();
    var width = element.parent().width();

    hover_in.css({
        display: 'block',
        width: width - 40,
        bottom: -hover_in_h * 3
    });

    $('img', this).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 200);
    hover_in.animate({
        bottom: -hover_in.height() * 3
    }, 200);
});

// Trigger initial state
$('.holder').trigger('mouseleave');
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/1fdfqpsq/3/

Note, you still need to at least run `$('.holder').trigger('mouseleave');` once you load any new elements. I am sure it is possible to get the initial state into the styling, but you would need to show more of your actual HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much. Tested with your sample and it's working out of box. Once again thanks ;)

Comment: @Madizm: Would have been much sooner if we'd had example HTML to begin with :)

Answer (score 0):

Move the `on()` functions outside the `each()` function. `each()` doesn't work with dynamically generated elements.

You would then have to move the variables inside the `on()` functions.

It should work.

**EDIT:** The functions should be delegated and rewritten as:

```
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.selector-class', function() {
```

Comment: This would help, but is missing a key point. They need to be *delegated* event handlers too.

Comment: `on()` is a delegated event. It replaces the deprecated `live()` and `delegate()`. I agree that the OP should rewrite the function as `$(document).on('mouseleave', '#selector', function() {`

Comment: Indeed. Your answer simply did not mention converting them to delegated.

Comment: Note: `#selector` (emphasis on `#`) is probably the worst example to give for a delegated handler as it implies ID matching (of which there can only be one match) :)

Comment: Better. Now just type up the whole solution, paint it green, and we are done :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting the events outside of each. I also created a seperate function called `ApplyEach`, you need to call it each time you bind new images.

//each time you bind some image, call this : ApplyEach

```
function ApplyEach(){
  $('.holder').each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var width = $(this).parent().width();
    var height = $(this).parent().height();
    var hover_in = $(this).find('.holder_in');
    var hover_in_w = $(this).find('.holder_in').width();
    var hover_in_h = $(this).find('.holder_in').height();

    $(this).data('bottom', -hover_in_h*3);

    hover_in.css({
        display: 'block',
        width: width - 40,
        bottom: -hover_in_h*3
       });
  });
}


$(document).on( 'mouseenter', '.holder', function() {
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        opacity: 0.8
    }, 200);
    $(this).find('.holder_in').animate({
        bottom: 20
    }, 200);
})

$(document).on( 'mouseleave', '.holder', function() {
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 200);
    $(this).find('.holder_in').animate({
        bottom: $(this).data('bottom');
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie only variable needed seems to be `-hover_in_h*3` and I think we can use `data` to attach this value to the image, see the update

Comment: Handy workaround. I would suggest simply refactoring the calculation to occur inside the mouse handlers, rather than a 2-stage approach. Then it will work for new items without calling `ApplyEach` :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `bind()` instead of `on()`, try it and tell me

Comment: `on` is now preferable to `bind` and allows for delegated event handlers (which are likely needed for this problem)